# custom styles maplotlib (.mplstyle)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

After building a custom style and saving it in a ".mplstyle" folder, I then import this mplstyle into a new script. Unfortunately I get some errors.

```
home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1102: UserWarning: Bad val "[3.7, 1.6]" on line #183
    "lines.dashed_pattern : [3.7, 1.6]
"
    in file "/home/plotting_tools/codepan.mplstyle"
    Key lines.dashed_pattern: Could not convert all entries to floats
  (val, error_details, msg))
/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1102: UserWarning: Bad val "[1.0, 1.65]" on line #184
    "lines.dotted_pattern : [1.0, 1.65]
"
    in file "/home/plotting_tools/codepan.mplstyle"
    Key lines.dotted_pattern: Could not convert all entries to floats
  (val, error_details, msg))

AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    332                 pass
    333             else:
--> 334                 return printer(obj)
    335             # Finally look for special method names
    336             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in <lambda>(fig)
    239 
    240     if 'png' in formats:
--> 241         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    242     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    243         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    123 
    124     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 125     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    126     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    127     if fmt == 'svg':

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2210                     orientation=orientation,
   2211                     dryrun=True,
-> 2212                     **kwargs)
   2213                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2214                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    511 
    512     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 513         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    514         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    515         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in draw(self)
    431             # if toolbar:
    432             #     toolbar.set_cursor(cursors.WAIT)
--> 433             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    434             # A GUI class may be need to update a window using this draw, so
    435             # don't forget to call the superclass.

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1470 
   1471             if self.frameon:
-> 1472                 self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1473 
   1474             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
    556             renderer = PathEffectRenderer(self.get_path_effects(), renderer)
    557 
--> 558         renderer.draw_path(gc, tpath, affine, rgbFace)
    559 
    560         gc.restore()

/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/patheffects.pyc in draw_path(self, gc, tpath, affine, rgbFace)
    107     def draw_path(self, gc, tpath, affine, rgbFace=None):
    108         for path_effect in self._path_effects:
--> 109             path_effect.draw_path(self._renderer, gc, tpath, affine,
    110                                   rgbFace)
    111 

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'draw_path'<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

I suspect it is something to do with how I format the ".mplstyle" file, but I'm not too sure. Let me know if you need further information about my computer or the script I'm running.

**EDIT**

Here's the code I use

```
# Example of Use
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.style.use("codepan.mplstyle")
plt.style.use('ggplot')

n = 50
raw_data = np.random.randn(n)*10

plt.plot(raw_data)
plt.show()
```

Here's a snippet from the mplstyle file

```
lines.dashdot_pattern : [6.4, 1.6, 1.0, 1.6]
lines.dashed_pattern : [3.7, 1.6]
lines.dotted_pattern : [1.0, 1.65]
```

Comment: How *exactly*  does your mplstyle file look like? How exactly do you try to use it. Without [mcve], there is little hope for help here.

Comment: shall I add the full mplstyle file to the post?

Comment: Not the full file. The error seems to come from some `lines.dashed_pattern` line in that file, so you can remove everything else from it that is not needed to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove the square brackets from those lines

i.e. they should look like:

```
lines.dashdot_pattern : 6.4, 1.6, 1.0, 1.6
lines.dashed_pattern : 3.7, 1.6
lines.dotted_pattern : 1.0, 1.65
```

See, for example, [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/5e52ce11ab59176a467dd2c68db8c5e1fbc20a24/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/classic.mplstyle#L18) in the `classic.mplstyle` example sheet.

Comment: the Attribute error linked to "draw_path" remains after fixing this

Comment: that suggests there are more issues in your style sheet... although without being able to see it, its hard to be sure